# Export BibLaTex format collection from Zotero to use in LyX

Tags: lyx, unicode, zotero

I'm trying to use a collection from Zotero in a LyX file as a reference database.

I export the Zotero collection as a BibLaTeX format database with unicode encoding. I've also tried using unicode without BOM and Western. All of them cause issues when compiling the document in LyX.

These are the options I use when exporting the collection:

[image]

This is the error I see when compiling:

[image]

I can remove the `—` from `{Test—with a dash}` to remove the error, but I'd have to find and replace unsupported characters each time I export.

Opening the exported BibLaTeX file in http://findencoding.com I see that the dash is replaced with a `�` under the `utf-8` section. So it seems that Zotero isn't actually exporting using the correct format. The `windows-*` sections have the dash correctly displayed.

```
@article{test_2018,
    title = {Test�with a dash},
    volume = {62},
    issn = {1231-1231},
    url = {http://ww.google.com},
    doi = {11.1111/1111-1111(11)11111-P},
    abstract = {Test},
    pages = {11-111},
    number = {111},
    journaltitle = {Test},
    shortjournal = {Test},
    author = {Test},
    urldate = {2018-01-01},
    date = {2018-01-01},
    keywords = {Test}
}
```

[Example files](https://gist.github.com/waspinator/8d3174fb364675b071a7cc24a384b1d8)

- LyX version: 2.3.0
- Zotero version: 5.0.52
- OS: macOS 10.13

Comment: You could try installing [BBT](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) into Zotero and then exporting in BBT biblatex with the "Export unicode as plain-text latex commands" preference on.

Comment: @retorquere thanks that worked. If you want to answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try installing the [Better BibTeX for Zotero (aka BBT)](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) plugin into Zotero and then exporting in BBT biblatex with the "Export unicode as plain-text latex commands" preference on in the settings.

Full disclosure: I am the author of the BBT plugin.